# Why does Mathematica ignore 1 as an exponent? Or as a coefficient?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

## Two different examples of same problem:

In: `Cases[{f^2, g^3, k^p, h}, x_^n_ -> n]`

Out: `{2,3,p}`     # The result misses the exponen of h, '1'

## The same problem in a different context:

In: `Cases[{f[a],2 f[b]}, f[x_] -> x]`

Out: `{a}`   # result misses b. A "fix" could be

```
Cases[{f[a],2 f[b]}, Real_ f[x_] -> x]
```

Out: `{b}`   #  now it misses 'a'  !!

Can this be solved, without resorting to Union of lists?

Comment: Hey MaxB! You might have a better response if you [format your question's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) in a way that makes it easier for others to help answer :D Look's like Rohit helped you out with this one :)

Comment: Pattern matching in Mathematica can sometimes be a bit surprising since the code the patterns search is not the same as what you see on the screen. In particular, you may be surprised by the output of `FullForm[1/Sqrt[2]]` if you ever need to pattern match square roots. Using `FullForm[{f^2, g^3, k^p, h}]` and `FullForm[{f[a], 2 f[b]}]` will allow you to see what Mathematica sees when it's searching through the expressions. In the first example, you can see that they all have `Power` except for the last one.

Answer (score 11):

You can find them all using

```
  Cases[{f^2, g^3, k^p, h}, x_^n_. :> n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same for the other one

```
 Cases[{f[a], 2 f[b]}, any_. f[x_] :> x]

 (* {a, b} *)
```

Or for the above  second example, you do not have to name it `any` or any other name since you are not using it, so you can also just do

```
  Cases[{f[a], 2 f[b]},  _.  f[x_] :> x]
  (* {a, b} *)
```

The rules are

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that it says `x_^n_` does not match `1` for `n`. Same thing for the second example.

I also changed `->` to `:>`. It is more safe this way. The rule of thumb for this, if `x_` or `n_` or whatever named pattern is used, shows up on left side then more safe to use `:>` to emit it on right side of the rule.

Learned this rule from `Power Programming with Mathematica: The Kernel Book by David B. Wagner` page 148,  where he gives an example of why this can make difference if delayed version is used or not.

```
ClearAll[u, y];
expr = Sqrt[u - 1]/Sqrt[u^2 - 1];
expr /. 1/Sqrt[y_] -> 1/Sqrt[Factor[y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to what happens when using `:>` instead of `->`

```
 expr /. 1/Sqrt[y_] :>  1/Sqrt[Factor[y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is what we wanted. Wagner gives the explanation of the difference as follows

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So when in doubt, or if something does not happen the way you expect it, use `:>` instead of `->`. In your examples, using `->` or `:>`  gives same result, since this issue does not show up. But in more complicated cases it can as in the example in the book above.

---

Here is summary of most important rules from my Mathematica cheat sheet collected from Wolfram help pages

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fantastic!  I knew there had to be a way but could find it myself. Thank you !

Comment: Hey @Nasser, it seems that the `any_.` syntax is more robust than just the `Power` example, as you show, can you point to a good resource on why this works? I didn't know about this! Very cool.

Comment: @CATrevillian most of these are given in different help pages. Please see [tutorial/Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#139) as an example.

Comment: @CATrevillian The head of `any_.` is [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 and Nasser, thanks to both of you for the clarification! Seems [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#17673) is specifically where I should look. Even still, it is quite new to me, and I wonder if one can define the default values as one sees fit! I know of the ability to define optional and default arguments in a function, but the `_.` syntax is new to and not yet understood by me.  Thanks also for the additional additional clarifications to your answer, Nasser!

Comment: "I wonder if one can define the default values as one sees fit!" - @CA, look up `Default[]` for this.