# Deletion of string characters by rule

Tags: string-manipulation

This seems simple:

Given

```
lis = {"abcd12efcdef"}
```

I would like to delete all instances of "ef" when it directly follows a digit character, to give:

```
res = {"abcd12cdef"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with positive look-behind:

```
s = "abcd12efcdef";
StringDelete[s, RegularExpression["(?<=\\d)ef"]]
(*    "abcd12cdef"    *)
```

Explanations:

- `\\d` is a digit character
- `(?<=...)` is a positive look-behind: in this case we only match `ef` if it is preceded by `\\d` (but we don't include the `\\d` in the match)

Answer (score 9):

One possible way could be:

```
lis = {"abcd12efcdef"};
StringReplace[#, k : DigitCharacter ~~ "ef" :> k, 1] & //@ lis
```

> `{"abcd12cdef"}`

**EDIT**

```
lis = {"abcd12efcdef", "abcd12efcdefa12efghef21"};
res1 = StringReplace[#, k : DigitCharacter ~~ "ef" :> k, 1] & //@ lis
res2 = StringReplace[#, k : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "ef" :> k] & /@ lis
```

> `{"abcd12cdef", "abcd12cdefa12ghef21"}`

```
res1 == res2
```

> True

`res2` is more idiomatic than `res1`.

Comment: +1 but I think `:>` intead of `->` would be better.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit this in.

Comment: @Nasser there's no need to delay the replacement in this case. In your opinion, what makes `:>` "better" than `->` when the right-hand side does not need delaying?

Comment: @Roman it is just a rule of thumb I use. Whenever the symbol shows up on the left hand (k here), better use `:>` when it also shows on the rhs. I know in this case it is the pattern name itself. But so not to worry, I just use `:>` for all cases. Here is a link [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221934/why-does-mathematica-ignore-1-as-an-exponent-or-as-a-coefficient) with screen shot from the book which recommends this. so delayed `:>` is safer in general.

Answer (score 2):

With rules, it is easier, as @Roman and @Syed answers show. However, here is a way to do it without rules:

```
    MyStringReplace[Pattern[lis, 
Blank[List]], Pattern[string2, 
Blank[]] ? StringQ] := {
    StringJoin[
            Delete[Flatten @ Map[Characters, lis],
                Outer[List,
                    Flatten[
                        Map[
                                Function[
                                    If[
                                        
          SameQ[DigitQ[Extract[Flatten @ Map[Characters, lis], {#}]], 
           True],
                                        Range[# + 1, # + 2],
                                        Nothing
                                    ]
                                ],
                                Map[
                                    (# - 1 &) @* ((Apply[Times, #] &) @* First),
                                    Transpose[
                                        Map[
                                            
           Function @ Position[Flatten @ Map[Characters, lis], #],
                                            Characters @ string2
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
   };
```

Examples:

```
lis0 = {"abcd12efcdef"};
lis1 = {"abcd12efcdefab3ef"};
lis2 = {"abcd12efcdefa12efghef21"};
```

Tests:

```
MyStringReplace[lis0, "ef"]
(*{"abcd12cdef"}*)
MyStringReplace[lis1, "ef"]
(*{"abcd12cdefab3"}*)
MyStringReplace[lis2, "ef"]
(*{"abcd12cdefa12ghef21"}*)
```

Comment: A related question, so I won't post it as a new question. I have lis = {"1","a","b","23","c","d","e" and need to join the adjacent non-digit characters to give: res={"1","ab","23","cde".